# The hmac 512 migration from Node.js to Python 3.6 results does not match

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, hmac, sha512

Now I'm developing hmac 512 migration from Node.js to Python 3.6. Two codes make different results. The Node.js results is correct.  The goal is to produce Python 3.6 code. Where should I do something for the problem ?

(1) Node.js

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var data = {
    'request' : '/api/v1/account/balances',
    'nonce'   : 1589963590749
 };

secret = "SECRET";
data = JSON.stringify(data);
payload = Buffer.from(data).toString('base64');

signature = crypto.createHmac('sha512', secret).update(payload).digest('hex');
console.log(signature);
```

"94e40c0ad3d14746e7a15c31d3b4f8e4060d4cec81cbc529bce2ae02a45bf2b0b8ed3ad0a7842b6b3d26fe9bec045a3cedc8b546bb1c4a921416f03ed98815fb"

(2) Python3.6

```
import hmac, hashlib, json, base64

data = {
    'request': '/api/v1/account/balances',
    'nonce'  : 1589963590749
}

secret = "SECRET"
data = json.dumps(data)
payload = base64.b64encode(data.encode())
secret = secret.encode()
signature = hmac.new(secret, payload, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
print(signature)
```

"9aaa9f01dd2ab21bfc46bb1e369748afc5f638fa157578078472219b9bc615f4796d7a9502efcf7c4fdc5208a52470c5b850257d0c36050c9b2650d277fa8f8c"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find an issue step by step:

1. Compare base64 encoded strings:

**JS:** `eyJyZXF1ZXN0IjoiL2FwaS92MS9hY2NvdW50L2JhbGFuY2VzIiwibm9uY2UiOjE1ODk5NjM1OTA3NDl9`
which is (decoded):

```
{"request":"/api/v1/account/balances","nonce":1589963590749}
```

**Python**:
`eyJyZXF1ZXN0IjogIi9hcGkvdjEvYWNjb3VudC9iYWxhbmNlcyIsICJub25jZSI6IDE1ODk5NjM1OTA3NDl9` which is (decoded):

```
{"request": "/api/v1/account/balances", "nonce": 1589963590749}
```

Can you see the difference? Yes, there's a space after a colon.

2. Find the way how to get rid of the trailing whitespaces, in your case you could dump via:

```
data = json.dumps(data, separators=(',', ':'))
```

Comment: Thank you so very much !!!!.    Amazing, it's working !.   God bless you !!!

Comment: spot on. You saved my hours